# MongoDB C# WPF чат

Tags: c#, wpf, mongodb

Есть приложение, одним из его важных частей является чат. Хранение аккаунтов, сообщений обязательно на MongoDB. Сама прога на WPF. Так вот, хотел бы спросить несколько советов:

1. Как в MongoDB организовать хранение данных (хотя бы сообщений (каждую беседу пользователей в отдельной коллекции или в одной)).
2. Как сделать чтобы сообщения обновлялись (Клиент отправляет в БД сообщение, а другой клиент должен его сразу же получить вытащив из БД (на ум только таймер приходит, который будет обращаться к MongoDB с определенным интервалом)).

Comment: 1. Не понятен вопрос. Вы не знаете как работать с базой этой или что? Создали там таблицу которая хранит что надо да и все. 2. Для таких целей обычно существует прямое соединение, либо CallBack (обычно он в Web). Я бы на вашем месте сделал бы сервер, который имеет доступ к базе, хранит все и по запросу отдает только нужную информацию через API. Клиент запускает приложение, авторизируется на этом сервере и сервер выдает ему JSON данные с его переписками, информации о нем и так далее. Чат бы я сделал наприрмер на SignalR, где при отправке сообщения сервер бы делал уведомление нужному человеку.

Comment: Проблема в том, что нужно именно использовать MongoDB для долговременного хранения информации. Насчет сервера я думал, но не знаю как его реализовать, с серверами не работал вообще.

Comment: А при чем тут `MongoDB` или другая? Выбирайте любую базу и используйте. А по поводу "не знаю как реализовать" - думаете вам тут это скажут?) Это довольно обширная тема, где в один ответ вряд-ли что уместится. Начните с простого, поймите как будет общаться сервер - клиент, через что? Дальше думайте как сервер будет обновлять данные у клиента и исходя из этого выбирайте на чем будет базироваться сервер.

Comment: То есть получится через сервер организовать? Схема такая: клиент1 отправляет сообщение => сервер принимает сообщение, записывает в БД => сервер отправляет сообщение клиенту2 => клиент2 принимает

Comment: БД конечно важный компонент, но при создании нового приложения начинать думать нужно не с того как вы будете хранить данные, а как их будете получать и обрабатывать.

Comment: Если у вас тет а тет чат, которым пользуются всего 2-е, то сервер вряд-ли вам нужен, ибо написали "Васек, дай свой ip", тот дает его, установили соединение через сокеты (или что либо еще) и общаетесь, попутно один хранит данные в базе. Если же у вас клиентов много и каждый должен приватно общаться со своим другом, то тут как не крути нужен сервер, который будет хранить и обрабатывать все входящие запросы. На сколько я помню, тот же SignalR работает по принципу: Клиент подсоединился, он имеет свой уникальный ID, ему теперь сервер может отправить данные. Вот так я бы лично реализовал.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать новую фишку mongo streams для моментальной отправки нового сообщения получателю, например на signalr

Comment: Что-то я нигде не нашел информацию про `mongostreams`